# MAM message encryption

Tags: transaction, tangle, security, privacy, masked-authenticated-messaging

According to the documentation message encryption is done in following way

> Each message is encrypted with a one-time pad that consists of the channel ID and the index of the key used to sign the message; an additional nonce may be used as a revocable encryption key.

[Source](https://blog.iota.org/introducing-masked-authenticated-messaging-e55c1822d50e)

In mathematical form is above statement means
`cipher = Message XOR ChannelID XOR IndexKey`

I am not understanding how is onetime pad key is computed using channel ID and index of the key used to sign the message.